# Marketing Cloud Connector Update

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, einstein-recommendations

Salesforce is suggesting we should update the way we update catalog into Marketing Cloud. It used to be done by a clint side javascript and now it must be done via API integration or by batch process.

I'm trying to develop this integration but I'm not quite sure how I should do it. When should I trigger the API request, in which events ?

This is the JSON I should send in the request instead of using collect.js. But I need to understand which events trigger the catalog update. Does anyone know ?

I noticed that in collect.js, there is a function called `updateItems` that I believe it is responsible for updating, but I'm not sure.

https://MID.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/update_item_secure.json

```json
{
  "api_key": "a1234567-cccc-1234-a123-12345a123456",
  "payload": {
    "item": "INSERT_ITEM",
    "unique_id": "INSERT_UNIQUE_ITEM_ID",
    "item_type": "INSERT_ITEM_TYPE",
    "name": "INSERT_ITEM_NAME_OR_TITLE",
    "url" : "INSERT_ITEM_URL",
    "INSERT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "INSERT_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should do a update to an item if any of the values in the fields you are supplying change such as Availability / Price / URL Etc